# notation structure confusion

Tags: notation

I am new to writing notations and therefore I lack a little bit the experience on how to express something very simple. Basically, I want to describe the euclidean distance between two RGB colors. Each of the two colors, however was derived from taking the mean of a color swatch.
I tried the following, but feel very illiterate:

I have to color swatches $\mathcal{S_1}$ and $\mathcal{S_2}$. Those color swatches in turn consist out of five RGB colors . 
$$\mathcal{S_1},\mathcal{S_1} = { c_{rgb_{1}} ... c_{rgb_{5}} }$$

Each RGB color consists of three values, which span from 0 to 255.

`how would this be expressed for each of the rgb channels?`
$$ c_{rgb_{i}} = {v | v \text{is an integer, and} 0 \geq v \leq 255 }$$

To measure the distance between those two swatches, I took the mean of all each channel r,g,b in s1 and the same with s2 to create two new cumultive RGB values.

`here I dont know how to express this`

Finally, these resulting RGB colors, I then used to calculate the Euclidean distance with:

\begin{equation}
dist = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{(}(R_i^a - R_i^b)^2 + (B_i^a - B_i^b)^2 + (G_i^a - G_i^b)^2)
\end{equation}

Thanks for the hints!

Comment: If you want to use the Euclidean distance you can but you can define all sorts of metrics on the set of swatches. You'll have to pick one.

Comment: If I use the Euclidean distance - would the approach like stated above correct on how to describe it? Sorry, I am currently learning all of this

Comment: Yes. You can think of colors as points in a three dimensional space with coordinates $(r,g,b)$ and then it inherits the usual Euclidean metric from $\mathbb{R}^3$. This generalizes to any number of dimensions. The colors would be lattice points. Also, the notation $c_{rgb1}$ seems excessive. I would just call this $c_1$ since the $rgb$ doesn't give us any new information.

Comment: Thank you!  for explaining a RGB color I can say this then?
$$ c_i =  \{ v \in \mathbb{N^3} \ |  0 \geq v \leq 255 \}$$

Comment: Yes but I think you mean $0 \leq v \leq 255$

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks!